# Microwave door switch comparison

Tags: repair, appliances, microwave-oven

I have a built in Viking microwave that works but does not heat. I took it apart and tested the door switches and sure enough one of them is no good.

My question is the following: the part listed for Viking costs $25.00, I have seen the part (switch) for as little as $3.00. How do I find out if these switches are compatible?

We paid close to $1000.00 in 2004/05 but did not install it until 2007, once the kitchen was finished. Also, Viking discontinued this model, vmos200. Absolutely not worth to pay hundreds of dollars to fix it, but because it was so expensive I can't just give up on it.

Comment: Google the part number on the side of the switch.
There aren't that many different kinds, as there are tremendous economies of scale, and almost all manufacturers use the cheapest ones.

Comment: It seems odd to me that the oven would even turn on and "work" if the switch was bad.  When you say "does not heat", will it not even start?  Does the light and fan come on, but the food doesn't get hot?

Comment: The two main things to look at on a switch are the physical size/shape, and if the switch is normally open or normally closed.  As long as those two things match, it will probably work.  The voltage and current the switch can handle normally don't matter in a situation like this where the switch is just a signal to a controller board, but checking those would be a good idea too.

Comment: Be careful; if you make a mistake you might disable the "door opens => turn off the magnetron" protection.

Answer (score 1):

The switches common on the doors of microwaves are called "micro switches". Probably due to there small size. They are made to function so that when the switch is activated current flows (normally open 'N.O') or when switched no current flows (normally closed 'N.C'). The group that rates and test these switches is the Underwriters Laboratories. They establish how much voltage each switch is able to safely tolerate. These are the numbers you should try to match to the new switch. They are embossed on the switch in very minute detail. Usually something like: 5A 125-250V AC.